# Manual value with a driver

Tags: rigging, drivers, pose-mode

I want to add a driver to the rotation of a bone in pose mode, but I also want to use that rotation manually. In other words, I want the rotation to be calculated by summing the manual value and the value from the driver.
Because I want to control that bone both with the data coming from the driver and manually at the same time, and as a result, I want the sum of the two to be calculated. Is something like this possible?

Comment: simple answer: no. the rotation is either controlled by driver or manually...but...what you could do, is use a custom property as your "manual" rotation. And then use that custom property in your driver to add it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @Chris I understand what you mean. What if I add 3 custom properties(x, y, z) for a rotation, can I control these custom properties by pressing the r(rotation shortcut) key? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Chris, but yes, it is possible. Why not?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: uhm...you just answered what i commented....so what is the problem? and no, also with "our" solution, you cannot manually change the rotation by "normally" changing rotation with mouse or values - that's all i said.

Comment: @gfytrbbbaa: with a script - for sure you can do that

Comment: @Chris. I am sorry, lack of sleep maybe. "no" is where I stopped reading. :D

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: ok...then go sleeping... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a custom property to the driver and then you can adjust it:

[image]

[image]

Or you could add rotation of another object like an empty. The empty could even have parent constraint for location so it would move with the controlled object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I add 3 custom properties(x, y, z) for a rotation, can I control these custom properties by pressing the r(rotation shortcut) key? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could add another object at the origin of the controlled one and add its rotation.

Comment: Martynas Žiemys I think you mean to create a fake bone for each bone I will use driver, rotate that fake bone manually and load its transform into the driver? I will try this. Thanks

Comment: I'll update the answer. Doesn't have to be a bone, can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but there is a "Delta Rotation" section in the Object Properties. You could *Copy as New Driver* this value and paste the Driver into the general Z Rotation and change the Driver Type to *Scripted Expression*.

From there, you can add more input variables to calculate to rotational sum. In this example, the Delta-Z-Rotation is added to the current frame count (divided by 100 for slower rotation):

[image]

The result is a steady rotation that can be manually accellerated or decelerated (even so much that it changes the spin direction).
Obviously, these manual modifications can be keyframed or even driven.

But there's a downside: The Delta Transform can (afaik) not be accessed by the <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut.

Here's the file; press play and drag the *Delta Transform > Rotation Z* slider:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess 'delta transform' was something that could fix the problem, but delta transform is only available for objects, there is no delta transform for 'pose bones'. If it was available, I could add a driver to the delta transform and use the original transform manually and the problem would be solved.

Comment: Oh, I see! Have to admit that I didn't check that. It's a pity that bones have no delta transform. I hope you can do it with the solution Martynas Žiemys provided.